# Why is this JavaScript cookie not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I know this code use to work, I must have accidentally changed something when rearranging  my div element that consisted of other code thus it does not seem to work now. I would deeply appreciate it if some one experienced with this to shed some light. Do I need "display:none;" on the window div? Sorry I don't remember.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     // If the 'hide cookie is not set we show the message
      if (!readCookie('hide')) {
        $('#window').show();
      }
      // Add the event that closes the popup and sets the cookie that tells us to
      // not show it again until one day has passed.
      $('#close').click(function() {
        $('#window').hide();
        createCookie('hide', true, 1)
        return false;
      });
    });
    // ---
    // And some generic cookie logic
    // ---
    function createCookie(name,value,days) {
      if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
      }
      else var expires = "";
      document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }
    function readCookie(name) {
      var nameEQ = name + "=";
      var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
      for(var i=0;i &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt; ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
      }
      return null;
    }
    function eraseCookie(name) {
      createCookie(name,"",-1);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work *how*? Doesn't get set? Doesn't get read? Gets read but doesn't hide/show the `div`?

Comment: what the hell is this `for(var i=0;i &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt; ca.length;i++)`?

Comment: Lol, maybe the code got encoded with entities :D

Comment: :( i just saw that, my html editor must have did that. I don't know what goes there :( sorry.

Comment: You should just replace the HTML gobbledygook with: `i < ca.length`. So the full line will be:       `for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {`

Comment: better and faster way would be to change the for into for(var i=0, len = ca.length;i < len;i++)

Comment: Well, if that's actually in your cource code, that's likely the problem. What I don't understand is why you didn't see any errors in the JS console

Comment: I think this was the original piece "for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++)" without quotes.

Comment: :D i think it worked > www.computersolutions.spruz.com

Comment: Don't all cookie values have to be strings? There may well be some implicit casting, but worth checking that `true` versus `"true"` in the event handler for the close click event is setting a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong in your for loop condition.

It should be

```
    for(var i=0;i<ca.length;i++)
```